# Query Filter for value from multidimensional dictionary?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset, multidimensional-array

I'm new to Python/Django and i have a question.
I need to get a QuerySet filtered by a Value from a multidimensional dictionary (JSONField).
So far, I got this:

```
def make_cond(name, value):
    from django.utils import simplejson
    cond = simplejson.dumps({key:value})[1:-1] # remove '{' and '}'
    return ' ' + cond # avoid '"'

Post.objects.filter(JSONField__contains=make_cond('key', 'value'))
```

That works, but only for the 1st dimension of the dict.
How can I reach the other dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL can't help you with that.

Given an arbitrary json object whose serialization might look like this,

```
'{"a": {"c": "C", "b": "B"}, "c": {}, "b": {"e": "E", "d": "D"}}'
```

you'd have to construct a LIKE clause that matches, say, the `{"a"`, then another `{` and then `"b": "B"` without caring what's in place of `"c": "C"`.  A LIKE clause supports wildcards only before and after, so you can't get what you want.

It's possible you could figure it out with a fulltext index; you could try Haystack or Sphinx for that.

The correct tool for the job, though, is a NoSQL database like mongodb.

Comment: Thanks, I took the Like clause ;)